# Is using external DAO jar/library of MyBatis possible?

Tags: spring, dao, mybatis, mapper

I want to make jar that consists of dao, domain(java class),mapper(xml) and mybatis-config.xml. This way, several projects can include the jar avoiding duplicated classes among the projects.

I made the jar but got following error.

It works fine when the classes, xml files are in the spring project instead of external jar.

```
ERROR [main] (org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager:314) - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@472b82e5] to prepare test instance [com.ktnet.ca.web.controller.CmpControllerTest@799eace3]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:154)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [test-database-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import com.test.ca.param cannot be resolved
    SearchParam cannot be resolved to a type
    SearchParam cannot be resolved to a type
    SearchParam cannot be resolved to a type

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
```

The spring config file is as follow.

```
    <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="ca-ds" p:mapperLocations="classpath:/com/test/ca/mapper/*mapper.xml"
        p:configLocation="classpath:/com/test/ca/mybatis-config.xml" />
```

Do anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: `The import com.test.ca.param cannot be resolved -- SearchParam cannot be resolved to a type`

Comment: But the package and class exist in the jar file. It works fine when the classes, xml files are in the spring project instead of external jar.

Comment: any proof that `com.test.ca.param.SearchParam` is actually in classpath?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am reading your question right:

You have mapper XML (under package `/com/test/ca/mapper/*mapper.xml`) in one JAR file, and seems lookup failed?

I believe it is the resource expression `"classpath:/com/test/ca/mapper/*mapper.xml"` causing the problem.  Spring is in fact doing a trick here to achieve wildcard.  It will first find a resources in classpath base on the path before wildcard (i.e. `/com/test/ca/mapper`).  For the first classpath element (JAR etc) containing such resource, it will use that specific JAR to search for `*mapper.xml`.

Therefore it is quite possibly that you have another JAR that have the directory `/com/test/ca/mapper` and Spring has "mistakenly" used that to find your `*mapper.xml`.

The way to solve is simple, change to use `classpath*:` instead of `classpath:`.  This will tell Spring to find from all classpath element instead of the first encountered one.

Comment: I tried with classpath*, but did not work. Thank you anyway for your description as I did not know about the way wildcard works.

Answer (score 0):

This issue caused by spring can't scan your mapper to do their DI. Let add component scan configuration point to your package in your jar file.